# Error in solve.default(A, b) : 'a' (4 x 1) must be square

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to use R's solve() function to find the solution to a system of linear equations. The coefficients matrix is 2X2. My code below is written into an R file that I execute after it finished being written

```
               strcat(Q, "A = array(c(");
               strcat(Q, numx);
               strcat(Q, ", ");
               strcat(Q, numx_2);
               strcat(Q, ", ");
               strcat(Q, numy);
               strcat(Q, ", ");
               strcat(Q, numy_2);
               strcat(Q, "), dim = c(2,2,1))\n");
               strcat(Q, "b = c(");
               strcat(Q, numz);
               strcat(Q, ", ");
               strcat(Q, numz_2);
               strcat(Q, ")\n");
               strcat(Q, "solve(A,b)\n");
```

I thought that `dim = c(2,2,1)` would create a single 2 X 2 array. However, I am getting,
`Error in solve.default(A, b) : 'a' (4 x 1) must be square`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dim = c(2,2)`

or `solve(A[,,1], b)` if you don't change `dim`

Comment: do the number of commas in `A[,,1]` depend on the size of the matrix? So a 3X3 matrix would be `solve(A[,,,1], b)` ?